# whole page navigation angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I'm new to angular and starting to get the hang of routing and components. However I have a question regarding:

- How I can navigate to a second page (component) and display only that content and not just load component data into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

[First page component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6S7.png)

[Second page component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK0xo.png)

When I click the button I want the whole page to display the second component data only. I basically would like to know how I can do whole page navigation in Angular 4.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ApplyComponent } from './apply/apply.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ApplyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'apply', component: ApplyComponent
    }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.componenter.html**

```
<div class="container">
<br><br>
<h1 class="header center orange-text">First page</h1>
<div class="row center">

</div>
<div class="row center">

<a
routerLink="/apply"
class="btn waves-effect waves-light"
type="submit" 
name="action">

Second page
</a>

</div>
<br><br>

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**apply.component (second page)**

```
<div class="container">
<br><br>
<h1 class="header center orange-text">Second page</h1>
<div class="row center">

</div>
<div class="row center">

<a
routerLink="/"
class="btn waves-effect waves-light"
type="submit" 
name="action">

Back
</a>

</div>
<br><br>

</div>
```

If you have any questions or need clarification don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks beforehand!
/E

Comment: There is no difference. Just make `<app-component>` so, that it doesn't show any content or border/margin besides the `<router-outlet>`

Comment: `router-outlet` is same as `component`, it's provided by `router` at `angular/core` and supported module to set route **easily**.

Comment: How do you mean exactly? Wouldn't I still need the button to be able to navigate to the second component? Now the second component just appends under the first component content :) @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Please show your code. If the 2nd components appends under the first, there is probably an issue with your code. Perhaps a missing `/` prefix in the routerLink path. I don't know what you mean with the button. You will need something the user can click on to initiate the navigation.

Comment: I posted the module and component code in the post. Tell me if you need additional information! @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: So the routes our have are `/` and `/apply`? What component should be shown when `/` is the active route?

Comment: The "/" route is basically a "back button" to the first page. @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can nest one component into another thereby keeping the parent component and then loading the child component within the parent. Components can also exist without being nested into another. Where you declare your component tags really matters.

Let's say we have site which has a navigation bar we want to show on all pages. First of all, a primary component (named `app.component`) which usually has the selector name `<app-root></app-root>` (that is if you create your angular project using the Angular cli) is inserted into the `index.html`, which loads the `app.component` when the application starts. Now, since we want to show the `navbar` on all pages, you can create a `navbar` component and place it's selector tags in the `app.component.html` (which is the view for app component) and also place your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . Since the app.component is the parent for all the other components, the `navbar` will show on every other component. Now, what if we can don't want the `navbar` to show on every component? Then we do the opposite, we don't place `<navbar></navbar>` in the root. We place it in the component where we want it to show and then every other child component will show it too. Now, every component that is placed in the app.component won't show the `navbar`

So in short, if you want to 'display the second component data only', make it a parent component. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: So what you mean is that I need to make a navigation with only Parencomponents? :) @Alf Moh

Comment: You make navigation depending on how you want your application to be structured. This link might help you. https://lishman.io/

Answer (score 0):

You need a route entry for `/` like shown in

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
    path: '', component: DummyComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    path: 'apply', component: ApplyComponent
}
])
```

for this you need some component (like `DummyComponent`) that might not have any content in the view. It is used just to satisfy the router.

`pathMatch: 'full'` is required for routes with an empty path `''` and no child routes.

Comment: Hm I'm trying to make this work. What do you mean "satisfy the router". Can you explain more? Will it be a empty "parent" component? @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: You can't have a router-outlet without a component. There aleays has to be an actibe route with a component.

Comment: I can't seem to get the dummy component to work. Could you please make @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: You already accepted the other answer. Why do you still need something?

Answer (score 0):

your app-root html and parent component will always display; what you need is the components of your front page in its own component.

```
> app-component (always displays) //the parent
>      child components
>             Home
>             About
>             Products
>             ...
```

your router can then route/display each component (using a navbar in the parent)